# IndexError: tuple index out of range ----- Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

Please Help me. I'm running a simple python program that will display the data from mySQL database in a tkinter form...

```
from Tkinter import *
import MySQLdb

def button_click():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500+10+10")
root.title("Ariba")

myContainer = Frame(root)
myContainer.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

db = MySQLdb.connect ("localhost","root","","chocoholics")
s = "Select * from member"
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(s)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

x = rows[1][1] + " " + rows[1][2]
myLabel1 = Label(myContainer, text = x)
y = rows[2][1] + " " + rows[2][2]
myLabel2 = Label(myContainer, text = y)
btn = Button(myContainer, text = "Quit", command=button_click, height=1, width=6)

myLabel1.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=BOTH)
myLabel2.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=BOTH)
btn.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=NONE)
```

Thats the whole program....

The error was

```
x = rows[1][1] + " " + rows[1][2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

y = rows[2][1] + " " + rows[2][2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can anyone help me??? im new in python.

Thank you so much....

Comment: It's saying that the index (position) you are accessing doesn't exist.

Comment: what code will i replace to my existing code??? Thank you

Comment: I don't know; could you provide a [small self-contained reproducible example](http://sscce.org/) and edit your question to include that.

Comment: You should try to print(rows) and print(rows[1]) to see what your data looks like. It may help you finding your problem.

Comment: was getting this error when i changed train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10)   to just train_sizes=10

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Probably one of the indices is wrong, either the inner one or the outer one.

I suspect you meant to say `[0]` where you said `[1]`, and `[1]` where you said `[2]`. Indices are 0-based in Python.

Comment: I was getting this message because I was passing an array to a function that was expecting a variadic sequence of arguments (eg `'{}{}'.format([1,2])` vs `'{}{}'.format(*[1,2])`

Comment: another situation was accidentally  having two  '{}' inside the string,  while only one variable/value in the .format()

Comment: If you have a misplaced assignment-operator (`=`) in an argument-list, that's another cause for this one. I had shuffled some code around and wound up with that.

Comment: ...and as a variant to Dror's comment: Having `{}` inside a format string instead of `{{}}`. This is a typical copy&paste error when someone wants to literally print a pair of curly braces.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945860/getting-error-when-converting-a-pyscript-to-exe-using-py2exe

Comment: In my case I started numbering of parameters in `print` from `1`, not from `0`. Example: `print({1}.format('Hello'))` should be `print({0}.format('Hello'))`

Answer (score 5):

A tuple consists of a number of values separated by commas. like

```
>>> t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!'
>>> t[0]
12345
```

tuple are index based (and also immutable) in Python.

Here in this case `x = rows[1][1] + " " + rows[1][2]` have only two index 0, 1 available but you are trying to access the 3rd index.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error with 
`query = "INSERT INTO table(field1, field2,...) VALUES (%s,%s,...)"` 
but in the statement
`cursor.execute(query, (field1, field2,..)` 
I had delivered less variables as necessary...
In this case I used

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
```

I just wanted to say that this is also possible...not only in arrays 
(I didn't have a very close look at this specific case...)

Answer (score -1):

This is because your *row* variable/tuple does not contain any value for that index. You can try printing the whole list like `print(row)` and check how many indexes there exists.