# How to fix "IndexError: tuple index out of range" in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am using `sklearn` modules to find the best fitting models and model parameters. However, I have an unexpected Index error down below:

```
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-38-ea3f99e30226> in <module>
>      22             s = mean_squared_error(y[ts], best_m.predict(X[ts]))
>      23             cv[i].append(s)
> ---> 24     print(np.mean(cv, 1))
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

what I want to do is to find best fitting regressor and its parameters, but I got above error. I looked into `SO` and tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296188/indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-python) but still, same error bumps up. any idea to fix this bug? can anyone point me out why this error happening? any thought?

**my code**:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge, Lasso
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor

from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

models = [SVR(), RandomForestRegressor(), LinearRegression(), Ridge(), Lasso(), XGBRegressor()]
params = [{'C': [0.01, 1]}, {'n_estimators': [10, 20]}]

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10000, n_features=20)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    cv = [[] for _ in range(len(models))]
    fold = KFold(5,shuffle=False)
    for tr, ts in fold.split(X):
        for i, (model, param) in enumerate(zip(models, params)):
            best_m = GridSearchCV(model, param)
            best_m.fit(X[tr], y[tr])
            s = mean_squared_error(y[ts], best_m.predict(X[ts]))
            cv[i].append(s)
    print(np.mean(cv, 1))
```

**desired output**:

if there is a way to fix up above error, I am expecting to pick up best-fitted models with parameters, then use it for estimation. Any idea to improve the above attempt? Thanks

Comment: @desertnaut Do you think how can I optimize this code? any better idea?

Comment: That's a very general question, but doing a grid search in *each* one of 5 folds sounds like overkill. I kindly suggest you open another question asking for advice in this (be sure to make your code fully reproducible, including all relevant imports).

Comment: The error can be reproduced with `np.mean([],1)`, which supports the idea the `cv` is `[]`, or contains `[]` lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your issue is that, while you ask for the evaluation of 6 models in `GridSearchCV`, you provide parameters only for the first 2 ones:

```
models = [SVR(), RandomForestRegressor(), LinearRegression(), Ridge(), Lasso(), XGBRegressor()]
params = [{'C': [0.01, 1]}, {'n_estimators': [10, 20]}]
```

The result of `enumerate(zip(models, params))` in this setting, i.e:

```
for i, (model, param) in enumerate(zip(models, params)):
    print((model, param))
```

is

```
(SVR(C=1.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, epsilon=0.1, gamma='auto',
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False), {'C': [0.01, 1]})
(RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse', max_depth=None,
           max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
           min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
           min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
           oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False), {'n_estimators': [10, 20]})
```

i.e the last 4 models are simply ignored, so you get empty entries for them in `cv`:

```
print(cv)
# result:
[[5950.6018771284835, 5987.293514740653, 6055.368320208183, 6099.316091619069, 6146.478702335218], [3625.3243553665975, 3301.3552182952058, 3404.3321983193728, 3521.5160621260898, 3561.254684271113], [], [], [], []]
```

which causes the downstream error when trying to get the `np.mean(cv, 1)`.

The solution, as already correctly pointed out by Psi in their answer, is to go for empty dictionaries in the models in which you actually **don't** perform any CV search; omitting the `XGBRegressor` (have not installed it), here are the results:

```
models = [SVR(), RandomForestRegressor(), LinearRegression(), Ridge(), Lasso()]
params2 = [{'C': [0.01, 1]}, {'n_estimators': [10, 20]}, {}, {}, {}]

cv = [[] for _ in range(len(models))]
fold = KFold(5,shuffle=False)
for tr, ts in fold.split(X):
    for i, (model, param) in enumerate(zip(models, params2)):
        best_m = GridSearchCV(model, param)
        best_m.fit(X[tr], y[tr])
        s = mean_squared_error(y[ts], best_m.predict(X[ts]))
        cv[i].append(s)
```

where `print(cv)` gives:

```
[[4048.660483326826, 3973.984055352062, 3847.7215568088545, 3907.0566348092684, 3820.0517432992765], [1037.9378737329769, 1025.237441119364, 1016.549294695313, 993.7083268195154, 963.8115632611381], [2.2948917095935095e-26, 1.971022007799432e-26, 4.1583774042712844e-26, 2.0229469068846665e-25, 1.9295075684919642e-26], [0.0003350178681602639, 0.0003297411022124562, 0.00030834076832371557, 0.0003355298330301431, 0.00032049282437794516], [10.372789356303688, 10.137748082073076, 10.136028304131141, 10.499159069700834, 9.80779910439471]]
```

and `print(np.mean(cv, 1))` works OK, giving:

```
[3.91949489e+03 1.00744890e+03 6.11665355e-26 3.25824479e-04
 1.01907048e+01]
```

So, in your case, you should indeed change `params` to:

```
params = [{'C': [0.01, 1]}, {'n_estimators': [10, 20]}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

as already suggested by Psi.

Answer (score 3):

When you define

```
cv = [[] for _ in range(len(models))]
```

it has an empty list for each model. 
In the loop, however, you go over `enumerate(zip(models, params))` which has only **two** elements, since your `params` list has two elements (because `list(zip(x,y))` [has length](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) equal to `min(len(x),len(y)`).

Hence, you get an `IndexError` because some of the lists in `cv` are empty (all but the first two) when you calculate the mean with `np.mean`.

**Solution:**
If you don't need to use `GridSearchCV` on the remaining models you may just extend the `params` list with empty dictionaries:

```
params = [{'C': [0.01, 1]}, {'n_estimators': [10, 20]}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer for this question. Please read `SO` community rule.

Comment: @Dan Since you haven't posted a MWE I can't verify with certainty that this is the solution, but it works with your code after importing the appropiate modules  and it matches the output you gave in the comments for `cv` (see the last edit for the specific change you would have to make to `params`).

Comment: This is the correct answer indeed (upvoted) - can't understand the downvotes; I proceed to explain in more detail...