# IndexError: tuple index out of range. issue occurred when restarted notebook

Tags: python

I keep getting the error IndexError: tuple index out of range and i am not sure what is happening. My code was working just fine however when i restarted the jupyter notebook i started receiving this error.

this is my code:

```
X = df.Tweet
y = df.target


from sklearn import linear_model
import pyswarms as ps

# Create an instance of the classifier
classifier = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

# Define objective function
def f_per_particle(m, alpha):

    total_features = X.shape[1]
    # Get the subset of the features from the binary mask
    if np.count_nonzero(m) == 0:
        X_subset = X
    else:
        X_subset = X[:,m==1]
    # Perform classification and store performance in P
    classifier.fit(X_subset, y)
    P = (classifier.predict(X_subset) == y).mean()
    # Compute for the objective function
    j = (alpha * (1.0 - P)
        + (1.0 - alpha) * (1 - (X_subset.shape[1] / total_features)))

    return j
```

[some more code]

```
options = {'c1': 0.5, 'c2': 0.5, 'w':0.9, 'k': 30, 'p':2}

# Call instance of PSO
dimensions = X.shape[1] # dimensions should be the number of features
optimizer = ps.discrete.BinaryPSO(n_particles=30, dimensions=dimensions, options=options)

# Perform optimization
cost, pos = optimizer.optimize(f, iters=1000)
```

i received the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-bea8cf064cd2> in <module>
      2 
      3 # Call instance of PSO
----> 4 dimensions = X.shape[1] # dimensions should be the number of features
      5 optimizer = ps.discrete.BinaryPSO(n_particles=30, dimensions=dimensions, options=options)
      6 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexError: tuple index out of range ----- Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296188/indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-python)

Comment: What is this line  X = df.Tweet? Like from where are you reading this? And what you can try is to print X before X.shape[1]

Comment: hello:)  X contains a list of tweets that have been transformed using tfidf/count vectorizer and y is a label assigned to thetweets. i am trying to use pyswarms based on the code: https://github.com/ahcantao/PSOFeatureSelection/blob/master/feature_subset_selection.ipynb. However my code was working just fine before i restarted the notebook and found it a bit weird. when i check x.shape[0] i get an output of 8324 and when i did x.shape[1] i got the error tuple index oyt of range . When i change my code to X.shape[0] i get the error ValueError: key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex.n

Answer (score 0):

It is not absolutely clear, but it seems to me that your `df` variable might be a Pandas dataframe, and your `df.Tweet` may be a Pandas series.

In that case, being a series, your `X` will have only one dimension (so, only the first element of the tuple `X.shape`, `X.shape[0]`), instead of two dimensions - reason for the index out of range exception in your code. The two dimensions case occurs only when the variable is a dataframe.

More information: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-shape/amp/

Comment: when i try to incorporate X.shape[0] i receive the error: ValueError: key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex

Comment: What do you have only with `X.shape`?

Comment: i get the result (8324,)

Comment: Ok, it is a tuple with only one element, as stated above. What do you mean by incorporate?